# Should I use inheritance for a bean?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I have a class with just getters and setters called Plane.

```
public static class Plane {
   String type = // [Commercial, Fighter]
   String numberOfWheels
   String manufacturer
   String numberOfEngines

   // getters and setters.
}
```

But now a requirement comes up, that we need a new kind of plane which is `amphibious` shares all the attributes of `commercial/fighter` but adds another field called `String pontoons`.

Now `pontoons` will not be used by anything other than `amphibious` planes, ie value is null.

Should i add a field to Plane class or go for inheritance?

Comment: What kinds of string values are you expecting `pontoons` to hold, or should it be a `boolean` instead? If there's only one (possibly enumerable) property that's different, you might not need to use inheritance.

Comment: Sometimes inheritance is overkill, but in this case, I'd go for it.  You can make `Amphibious` an interface if you have other vehicles that can take on amphibious properties in common (like a car or hovercraft, for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a typical use case for inheritance.

```
public class AmphibiousPlane extends Plane {

     private String pontoons;

     // getter, setter for pontoons field
}
```

You gave the reasons: normal planes *don't have* pontoons so pontoons do not belong to the Plane model.

The type could be an `enum`, btw.